# How to Solve Composite Trigonometric Functional equation

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations

I am stuck trying to solve the following functional equation for $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$\tanh{(h(c(g))} = \tanh^2{(h(g))}$,

where $c(g) = \frac{1}{4}\left(2+7g - (5g+2)\cos(\pi g)\right)$.

I have tried expanding $h$, $\tanh$ and $c$ as power series then solving for the coefficients of $h$ recursively but that did not work. I'm not sure if $h$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions either.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you explain where does this functional equation comes from?

Comment: @Jakobian A friend of mine gave it to me last week and bet I couldn't solve it. I'm not sure where he got it from.